# How to see that a constant method threw an exception?

Tags: solidity, exceptions

Consider this contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract GoodAndBad {

  function exec(uint flag) public constant returns (uint) {
    assert(flag == 1);
    return 0;
  }

}
```

How do I know that calling method exec() using web3.js or geth JSON RPC was successful and I received a number?

If it is not possible what is the best practice for the methods like above?

Comment: Note that with a constant function, clients will likely try to run it locally instead of issuing a transaction. There is no way for you to collect information about function calls that are run locally on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `event` to confirm result, as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract GoodAndBad {

    uint result = 0;
    event onResult(bool flag,uint result);

    function exec(uint flag) public returns (uint) {
        if (flag != 1) {
            result = 0;
            onResult(false,result);
            return;
        }
        result = 1;
        onResult(true,result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

and then deploy contract, set a watcher, and call `exec` method.